# Regex / DOM Parsing to replace YouTube iframes with thumbnails while keeping the String

Tags: php, regex, dom

I don't know if it's best to use a DOM parser or regex for this, but I want to replace all the YouTube iframes in my blogposts with the thumbnails. I've found methods of returning all the thumbs indeed, but not while still in the string. I want to keep the string as it is, but replace the Iframes with the thumbnails.

This code returns all YouTube videos:

```
$data = get_the_content();

// Find all unique YouTube videos
$re_youtube = '%youtube\.com/(?:v/|watch\?v=|embed/)(\w{10,12})\b%';
$count = preg_match_all($re_youtube, $data, $matches);


for ($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) {
$videos[$matches[1][$i]] = 'yt';
}

foreach ( $videos as $video => $v) {
    if ( $v == 'yt' ) { 
    echo '<div id="yt_'.$video.'" class="viddid viddid_thumb" onclick="myFunction(\''.$video.'\')"><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/'.$video.'/0.jpg"></div>';
    }
}
```

I'm sure I could use preg_replace to achieve what I'm looking for? I'm super happy for any help!

I've been doing some dome parsing to clean up the paragraphs in my HTML. It looks like this:

```
// Set the right encoding of string
$content = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'html-entities', 'utf-8'); 

$DOM = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$DOM->substituteEntities = TRUE;    
$DOM->loadHTML($content);
foreach($DOM->getElementsByTagName("iframe") as $iframe)
{
    foreach($p->attributes as $attr)

        $p->parentNode->removeChild($p);        
}

$content = $DOM->saveHTML();
```

So now I kind of need some help to combine the two of them-ish.

(Here is an example to the page where this is going to work:
http://2famous.tv/2013/11/17/middle-eastern-artists-donate-more-than-1-1-million-of-art-to-help-syrian-refugee-children/)

Comment: Yeah it is better to use DOM.

Comment: OK, cool. That helps... how do I go about and do it?

Comment: I was afraid that you will ask that! :) It's friday and I'm sooo lazy!!! :) can you post a snippet of the html in question? Then I will code an example

Comment: Haha, ok, sorry :P It seems like most of the people here are on US time, so I find myself more lucky at night than during the day.

Anyways, I've updated my question with a tad more information. I put in a DOM parser that I've been using to clean out image caption, and I put a link to a page where this typically is going to work so you can see the HTML. 

(I need to make my pages feather light as most viewers are in Lebanon and Syria where the internet is super duper slow)

Comment: Can you post the output of `var_dump($data);` to `pastebin.com` and post the link here?

Comment: Here you go: http://pastebin.com/TgMfXSvr

Comment: So the iframes of interest can be identified by having a `src` attribute which's value is starting with `//www.youtube.com` ?

Comment: Yessss, that is correct. Tagname Iframe with attribute SRC

Comment: Check my answer. Have tested with the snippet from pastebin.com

Comment: Does it work for you?

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so so much! You really saved my weekend there. Thank you so much!

Comment: Greets back to Lebanon :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `DOM` and `XPath` for that:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($your_html_string);
$selector = new DOMXPath($doc);

// use the starts-with function to select iframes of interest
foreach($selector->query('//iframe[starts-with(@src, "//www.youtube.com")]')
    as $iframe
) {
    $iframe->parentNode->removeChild($iframe);
}
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```